# Write a SQL query to retrieve a list of all films that are not in inventory. Sort the results by film rating and title

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL query to retrieve a list of all films that are not in inventory. In inventory meaning any store that has at least one copy of the film. Sort the results by film rating and title

This is what I have so far:

```
select f.film_id as "Film ID", f.title as Title, f.release_year as "Release Year", f.rating as Rating, f.description as description
from film f,inventory i
```

But am unsure what do from there, like what kind of WHERE would help me here.

Here's the ERD:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM05t.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Take the time NOW to learn proper JOIN syntax as you go too. Comma-separated tables in the FROM clause is literally a 30 year old standard. What you have now, will return a cross product result of the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a left join the query return all records from the first table and matches from the second. If there are no matches the columns queries from the second table will be null.
To only have the non matching columns where use `is null` in `where`.

```
select 
  f.film_id as "Film ID", 
  f.title as Title, 
  f.release_year as "Release Year", 
  f.rating as Rating, 
  f.description as description
from  
  film f,
left join
  inventory i on f.film_id = i.film_id
where
  inventory_id is null;
```